# event.preventDefault() in Meteor app does not work for Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, meteor

I'm following tutorial for Meteor: http://meteortips.com/first-meteor-tutorial/forms/

I have this for submitting a form:

```
    'submit form': function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        var plname = event.target.playerName.value;
        var uid = Meteor.userId();
        playersList.insert({ name: plname, score: 0, 'createdBy': uid });
        event.target.playerName.value = '';
        return false;
    }
```

Now, this works flawlessly in Chrome, a player is added on filling the form and hitting Enter or clicking the button:

[image: http://meteortips.com/images/first-meteor-tutorial/forms/1.png]

However, this does not work in Firefox for Linux. While in Chrome I do not see page reloading, in Firefox it clearly reloads. A player is not added. Meteor server side log does not show any error. Firebug's console does not show any error either.

This leads me to suspect that `event.preventDefault();` is not working.

What is the reason for that?

How can I fix that?

Firefox for Ubuntu Linux, `49.0.2`.

Meteor version `1.4.2.3`.

Node: `v4.2.6`.

Comment: you need to pass `event` to the function (this is covered in the tutorial you posted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome and IE support a global `event` object, Firefox doesn't, so you should always use the `event` argument

```
'submit form': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var plname = event.target.playerName.value;
    var uid = Meteor.userId();
    playersList.insert({ name: plname, score: 0, 'createdBy': uid });
    event.target.playerName.value = '';
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'll accept your answer, but does not omitting event make it `undefined`? If so, why calling `event` methods does not cause `ReferenceError`?

Comment: It could be you have something called `event` in that scope, but yes, generally you should get an error in Firefox as `event` would be undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the submit event inside Template.addPlayerForm.events instead of Template.leaderboard.events.

Code :

```
Template.addPlayerForm.events({  
 'submit form': function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     console.log("Form submitted");
     console.log(event.type);  
} 
});
```